How to Restore All Default Icons on Mac After Installing Cursor IDE
I installed Cursor IDE, and all the default icons on my MacBook have been changed. I want to know how to restore all icons back to their original state.
I’ve done some Googling and found ways to change the icon for individual files or folders. However, I’m looking for a solution that allows me to restore or change the icons for all file types at once, not just one file or folder at a time.

Have you found a way?

No, I didn't...

Clear the cache of icons.
Run this in your terminal
sudo rm -rfv /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store; sudo find /private/var/folders/ \( -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -or -name com.apple.iconservices \) -exec rm -rfv {} \; ; sleep 3;sudo touch /Applications/* ; killall Dock; killall Finder

Source

Executing this command did not solve the problem, so I just deleted the cursor app to resolve the issue. Thank you for your answer.
I'm curious if deleting the cursor icon within the cursor app might solve the problem, but since I don't use cursor anyway, I just gave up on it.
